# show convergence of a sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{na+b}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

show convergence of a sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{na+b}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$

From rough work $$ n > \frac{(\frac{1}{\epsilon}) - |b|}{|a|}$$

Given $\epsilon $ , chose $$ n > \frac{(\frac{1}{\epsilon}) - |b|}{|a|}$$

now $$|x_n - 0 | = |\frac{1}{na+b}|. \geq \frac{1}{n|a|+|b|} < \epsilon $$
somehow if i can find lower bound for |$an+b$|, then maybe i can do it

How do i proceed ?

Comment: As a simple approach, you can also consider the four cases: $a>0,b>0;a>0,b<0;a<0,b>0;a<0,b<0$. (the case $b=0$ is straightforward).

Comment: @Snoop yeah that's what i was thinking..

Comment: Do not forgrt that the triangle inequality also has another form: $||x|-|y||\le |x-y|$, so $|an+b|=|an-(-b)|\ge ||an|-|b||$. Note that $\exists N_1$ s.t. $\forall n>N_1$ $|an|>|b|$, and $||an|-|b||=|an|-|b|$. So for $n>N_1$ $|an+b|>|an|-|b|\Rightarrow \frac{1}{|an+b|}<\frac{1}{|an|-|b|}$

Comment: @Asigan can u explain why  " Note that ∃N1
 s.t. ∀n>N1
 |an|>|b|
"

Comment: @Asigan if you add enough a together you end up above b, that's the idea with the multiplication by n

Comment: @Olivia $|an|>|b|\Longleftrightarrow |n|>\frac{|b|}{|a|}=|\frac{b}{a}|$ (since $a\ne 0$). So select $N_1$ to be the least integer that is non-less than $|\frac{b}{a}|$. If $n>N_1$ then $n>N_1\ge |\frac{b}{a}|\Rightarrow |an|>|b|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{na+b}$ converges, given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$, we will use the definition of convergence. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We want to find an $N$ such that for all $n > N$, we have $|x_n - 0| = \left|\frac{1}{na+b}\right| < \epsilon$.

To find a lower bound for $|na+b|$, notice that since $a \neq 0$, we can write: $|na+b| = |a|\cdot|n+\frac{b}{a}| \geq |a|\cdot|n - |\frac{b}{a}| |$.

Now, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon|a|} + |\frac{b}{a}|$. Then for all $n > N$, we have: $|na+b| \geq |a|\cdot|n - |\frac{b}{a}| | > |a|\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon|a|}\right) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Taking the reciprocal of both sides, we get: $\left|\frac{1}{na+b}\right| < \epsilon$. Thus, $|x_n - 0| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$, which means the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{na+b}$ converges to 0.